# why doesn't radio button click event persist the update to the cells?

Tags: jqgrid, radio-button, persist

Description: Using `jqGrid.importGrid` `imptype:json` to import JSON grid and then allow administrator to "work" on local data by changing the status of radio button groups across columns (all rows in Column 1 default to `checked="checked"` and that status is changed (`checked=""`) by clicking another radio button in the same row (same radio button group) in say Column 3. In the Column 3 radio button click event an AJAX update to database records the Column 3 checked status and because `loadonce:true` is set a JSON is returned with only the HTML radio button code to replace the 2 cells in the same row of Column 1 and Column 3 with the new checked status's and background color changes. Keeping in mind that these options are set: `datatype:local, loadonce:true,`, after getting the AJAX JSON response containing the new radio button html in the radio button click event and using `setCell` to update the cells it does not seem to persist the update. If I navigate to the next page of the local data and then navigate back the radio button changes revert to the original local data version. I'm using jgGrid.importGrid so that paging is available on local data. I have other reasons for using the .importGrid method which aren't relevant to describe I don't think at the moment.

Here is the inital "loaded once" server generated grid code (jqGrid.importGrid's `url: dynamicGrid.ashx`):

```
/*C#*/
/* -- Declarations --*/
int NumberOfRecords; //from db table
int PageSize; 
int NumberOfPages; //from SQL based on NumberOfRecords and PageSize

StringBuilder bldrColNames = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder bldrColModel = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder bldrData = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder bldrGrid = new StringBuilder();

string pchecked = "checked='checked'";
string achecked = "checked=''";
string xchecked = "checked=''";

/* -- Default load once colNames -- */
bldrColNames.Append("[\"Pending\",\"Approved\",\"Declined\"]");

/* -- Default load once colModel -- */
bldrColModel.Append("[");
bldrColModel.Append("{\"name\":\"pending\",\"index\":\"pending\",\"jsonmap\":\"pending\",\"key\":true},");
bldrColModel.Append("{\"name\":\"approved\",\"index\":\"approved\",\"jsonmap\":\"approved\"},");
bldrColModel.Append("{\"name\":\"declined\",\"index\":\"declined\",\"jsonmap\":\"declined\"}");
bldrColModel.Append("]");

/* -- Default load once DATA ("Pending" column cells bgcolor default to yellow -- */
bldrGrid.Append("{\"id\":12345,\"row\":");
bldrGrid.Append("\"<span style='background-color:Yellow; background-image:none;'><input type='radio' name='12345' value='p' " + pchecked + "/></span>\",");
bldrGrid.Append("\"<span style='background-color:White; background-image:none;'><input type='radio' name='12345' value='a' " + achecked + "/></span>\",");
bldrGrid.Append("\"<span style='background-color:White; background-image:none;'><input type='radio' name='12345' value='x' " + xchecked + "/></span>\",");

/* -- JSON -- */
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

bldrGrid.Append("{\"grid\":");
bldrGrid.Append("{\"page\":\"1\",\"rowNum\":\"" + PageSize + "\",\"total\":\"" + NumberOfPages + "\",\"records\":\"" + NumberOfRecords + "\",\"sortname\":\"id\",\"pager\":\"#pmyGrid\",\"caption\":\"Approval Updates\",\"hidegrid\":false, \"url\":\"\",\"editurl\":\"clientArray\",\"loadonce\":true,\"datatype\":\"local\",");
bldrGrid.Append("\"colModel\":" + bldrColModel + ",\"data\":[" + bldrData + "],");
bldrGrid.Append("\"rowList\":[\"25\",\"35\",\"50\"],");
bldrGrid.Append("\"colNames\":" + bldrColNames + ",");
bldrGrid.Append("\"jsonReader\":{\"root\":\"data\",\"page\":\"1\",\"total\":\"" + NumberOfPages + "\",\"records\":\"" + NumberOfRecords + "\",\"repeatitems\":true,\"cell\":\"row\",\"id\":\"id\"},");
bldrGrid.Append("\"localReader\":{\"root\":\"data\",\"page\":\"1\",\"total\":\"" + NumberOfPages + "\",\"records\":\"" + NumberOfRecords + "\",\"repeatitems\":true,\"cell\":\"row\",\"id\":\"id\"},");
bldrGrid.Append("\"viewrecords\":true,\"height\":450, \"width\":1000}");
bldrGrid.Append("}");
```

Here is the jqGrid.importGrid, radio button click event, AJAX and returned JSON:

```
$("#myGrid").jqGridImport({
        imptype: "json",
        //impstring: jsonData,
        impurl: 'dynamicGrid.ashx,
        datatype: "local",
        jsonGrid: {
            config: "grid",
            data: "data"
        },
        importComplete: function () {

            $("#myGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'local' });

            $(":radio").live('click', function (event) {

            // depending on which radio button is clicked the AJAX url .asp file below gets
            // the record id from the radio button "name" and the character "value" ('p' or 'a' or 'x') stored in the "name".

            var vData = "" + $(this).attr('name') + "=" + $(this).val();

            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "get_JSON_radios.asp", //returns rowid and new radio button html to update cells with as shown in the JSON below
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: vData,
                complete: function (xhr) {

                oJSON = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                var rowid = '', pending = '', approved = '';

                for (var name in oJSON) {

                     if (oJSON[name].rowid) {
                         rowid = oJSON[name].rowid;
                      } else if (oJSON[name].pending) {
                         pending = oJSON[name].pending;
                      } else if (oJSON[name].approved) {
                         approved = oJSON[name].approved;
                      }

                 }

  // assuming an "Approved" column radio button was clicked, attempt to modify 
  // local data here with returned JSON but does not persist when paging back and forth...
  // (note: only including 2 of the 3 radios here pending/approved, "declined" is affected)

    $("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'pending', pending, { background: 'White', weightfont: 'normal' });
    $("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'approved', approved, { background: 'Green', weightfont: 'normal' });

    } // end complete

  }); // end ajax

 }
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pmyGrid', {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false,
        search: false

    }); // end myGrid
```

Returned JSON from AJAX url:

```
'this is assuming an "Approved" column radio button was clicked

Response.Write "[{""rowid"":12345},{""pending"":""<span style='background-color:White; background-image:none;'><input type='radio' name='12345' value='p'></span>""},{""approved"":""<span style='background-color:Green; background-image:none;'><input type='radio' name='12345' checked='checked'></span>""}]"
```

(According to Firebug the JSON in both cases - initial and ajax return - are fine and the grid displayed shows the new radio button HTML displaying in the cells as expected  but when paging back and forth the updated cells revert to original state rather than persist)

Lastly what the administrator is doing here only has to persist as long as he/she is updating the radio button columns, the underlying AJAX updates the remote database so when the grid is refreshed or closed the changes are already recorded and would appear in a reloaded import.

Can anyone determine why the changes to the local data cells do not persist when paging back and forth considering the imported grid url is `url:""` and `loadonce:true` and `dataype:local` and `editurl:clientArray`? Many TIA

**UPDATE**

I have checked and rechecked the JSON grid structure and data that is imported by `.jqGridImport` and all options are set for working on local data only: `loadonce:true, datatype:local, editurl:clientArray`, it all seems fine according to Firebug and JSON validation webpage and the records display as expected in the grid. The problem that I've been trying resolve on and off for nearly a week now is that when I click a radio button to update another cell in the same row (which it does do and I see the cell change value) and then navigate to the next page and back, that changed cell reverts to the visible content that was originally imported. I just want to work on the local data and have it persist page to page and back and have tried to change the internal dataArray and the visible grid data cell using the following:

```
        $("#myGrid").jqGridImport({
        imptype: "json",
        //impstring: jsonData,
        impurl: 'grid_json.ashx,
        mtype: 'Get',
        datatype: "local",
        jsonGrid: {
            config: "grid",
            data: "data"
        },
        onPaging: function () {

        },
        importComplete: function () {

            $("#myGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'local' });

            $(":radio").live('click', function (event) {

                var rowid = $(this).attr('rowid');

                var $myGrid = jQuery("#cma")

                var dataArray = $myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'),
                indexes = $myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');


                 var rows = dataArray[indexes[rowid]];

                 rows.myCellToEdit = "asdfasdf";
                 //or could be rows['myCellToEdit'] = "asdfasdf";

                 //now show what internal grid dataArray contains for the changed cell
                   alert(rows.myCellToEdit);

                 //now write same change to visible grid cell. (also eliminates need to use .trigger('reloadGrid');)

                    $('#myGrid').jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'pending', rows['pending']);
    }
}
```

The alert shows the internal data array has the change and the visible grid cell is changed according to the `setCell` method (I can see it with my own eyes) but when I navigate to the next page and back the change is not retained. Can someone please help me with this. It defies logic what I'm seeing according to the dozens and dozens of examples and similar scenarios I've studied and I have tested so many variations applying what I've tried to ascertain from all I've looked at and through.  I've explicity read that the local data that loaded from the server and then worked on can be paged through and the changes persist page to page so I just cannot "see" what I'm doing wrong or missing. TIA for any ideas.